# Получаю exception при запуске программы с использованием Boost:Procces (c++)

Tags: c++, исключения, boost

Получаю exception при запуске программы с использованием Boost:Procces (c++)

Для работы над заданием из университета требовалось устрановить библиотеку Boost:Procces.
Выполнил все требования для установки описаные в документации, проверил работоспособность на примерах,
после чего я попробовал использовать пример импользования Boost:Procces, указаный опять таки в офф гайде.

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::process;

int main()
{
    ipstream pipe_stream;
    child c("gcc --version", std_out > pipe_stream);

    std::string line;

    while (pipe_stream && std::getline(pipe_stream, line) && !line.empty())
        std::cerr << line << std::endl;

    c.wait();
}
```

Как я установил, во время создания **сhild c** вызывается такое исключение

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x752F44C2 в example.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: boost::process::process_error по адресу памяти 0x0056F00C.

Я пытался найти какие-то способы решения, к сожалению, безрезультатно. У меня не много опыта, так что возможно поэтому я не понимаю, что нужно делать в таком случае. Буду благодарен за помощь

Стоит так же указать сообщение при исключении - "CreateProcess failed"

Comment: а у вас gcc установлен?

Comment: @timur да, команда gcc --version в консоли работает

Comment: Проблема была решена перезагрузкой компьютера, я так не понял что именно ее вызвало

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар подсказывает, что путь к `gcc` был прописан в переменных окружения, однако при их изменении в уже запущенных процессах они остаются прежними, соответственно процесс и не запускался. Следует всегда использовать полные пути к файлам.